# Executing typescript class in same file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have one typescript file which I have added as required in another .ts file. I need to take the url from browser and need to do some manipulation and export it.

The class section does not seems to be executing. Seems i am missing a piece of code somewhere. Do not know what?

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export let someVariable="SomeValue"
export class RouteComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(path => {
      someVariable = path.url
    });
  }
  decideRoute(){

    // Want to do something with someVariable here
    console.log(someVariable)
  }
  ngOnInit(){
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling the class that's not executing?

Comment: Are you using Angular 1.x or Angular 2? You have both the `angularjs` tag, which is solely for Angular 1.x, and `angular2` which is for Angular2. For this question, I expect you're not including the script file in either your HTML or your build process.

Comment: var RouteJs = require("./route.component.ts");

Comment: Using Angular2 rc.5

Comment: I am perfectly able to receive the someVariable inside where I have required it. But the class does not seems to be executing.

Comment: what do you mean with "class is not executed"? someVar is not assigned? or your `decideRoute` function is not called?

Comment: MXII- Both has dependency on execution of class. However this piece of code works perfectly when I Import, it define Component decorator for it. However I am putting it to as require this time.